# How to parse a .m file in shell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linux, xcode, shell

I need to parse all .m files in a directory and its subdirectories for the occurrent of `[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:` or `[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:` then I need to get the `NSString` between the `"`. 
For example:

1st option: `[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:@"I need this string"];`

2nd option `[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I need this string with formate %@", [self someFormatedString]]];`

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want, but this looks like it might be a good starting point:

```
find . -name \*.m -exec grep "\[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:" {} \; | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

That says to find all files whose names end in `.m` in the current directory and below and grep for lines containing the "POEditor" string you want. Pass all results into `awk` and use `"` as the field separator and print field 2 of each line found.

If your `grep` supports the `-R` (recursive search) option, you may get away with this:

```
grep -R "\[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:" *.m */*.m | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

If you want the results in a `bash` array, you will need to initialise the contents of an array to the output of a command, like this:

```
array=( $(command) )
```

So you would use:

```
array=($(grep -R "\[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:" *.m */*.m | awk -F\" '{print $2}'))
```

but that will split array elements on the spaces and ${array[0]} will be "I" from "I need this", so you want to split array elements on line ends like this:

```
IFS=$'\n' array=($(grep -R "\[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:" *.m */*.m | awk -F\" '{print $2}'))
```

or equally

```
IFS=$'\n' array=($(find . -name \*.m -exec grep "\[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:" {} \; | awk -F\" '{print $2}'))
```

Then you can access the array elements like this:

```
echo ${array[0]}
I need this string
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome, thanks! Now I just need to know how to add $2 into an array, I already tried $stringArray
find . -name \*.m -exec grep "\[POEditor localizedStringWithKey:" {} \; | awk -F \" stringArray[i++]=$2 but somehow it won't work and I can't figure it out. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: An array? I didn't see that in the question. Do you mean a `bash` array? Or an `awk` array? Or an Objective-C array?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to add every string that is been found into a bash array.